# is timer efficient?

Tags: c#, performance, timer

I have created an application that is used to read a mail box at certain intervals. If there is a new mail it downloads the attachment creates pdf files say 100 + combines it and mail it back to a particular list. Due to some server policies am in a position to convert it to a window service. I have used a timer my code given below

```
private System.Threading.Timer timer;
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerTick, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

void TimerTick(object state)
{
  var minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
  if (minute != lastMinute && minute % 5 == 0)
  {
    //check mail here
  }
}
```

Is implementing a timer like this an efficient way of doing this? Is there any better way to handle this? I am worried about the performance because the applications need to run 24 x7 and hence can end up in utilizing more cpu memory if inefficient.

***is timer the only best available option in this scenario ?***

Comment: Why not use software that is designed for this situation? For example, VisualCron (http://www.visualcron.com/).

Comment: The timer will only consume a very tiny fraction compared to the SMTP client.

Comment: Everything is efficient unless proven otherwise. :) Meaning you should not be over-conscious regarding your code performance. This, however, does not mean you should not conduct performance testing in stress conditions.

Comment: @m-y not looking for any costly third party tools :(

Comment: @downvoter care to say the reason?

Comment: @Neolisk thank you .. i just wanted to know if timer was the best available option in this scenario

Comment: How you access the mail boxes? Outlook interop?

Comment: @CSharper no i use openpop.net

Comment: Okay. Its only you should care about memory leaks, when your service is running 7x24. In COM interop it's important to release the handles etc. Monitor your memory usage, do not forget to dispose your objects..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should monitor you service for performance. If you see there a performance problem:

1. measure it
2. change your code
3. measure again
4. than compare your measurments

`System.Threading.Timer` is a simple, lightweight timer that uses callback methods and is served by threadpool threads.

- You might consider `System.Timers.Timer` for server-based timer
  functionality.

Maintainability and debug tips:

- Use a XML config file to set the interval, without change your code.
  This will simply give you or administrators control about the service.

Use the code for easy debugging your service:

```
static void Main()
{
#if (!DEBUG)
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new Service1() };
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#else
    // Debug code: this allows the process to run as a non-service.
    // It will kick off the service start point, but never kill it.
    // Shut down the debugger to exit
    Service1 service = new Service1();
    service.EntryMethodHere(); // Your method that activates your timer
    // Put a breakpoint on the following line to always catch
    // your service when it has finished its work
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
#endif 
}
```

Comment: System.Timers.Timer contains a System.Threading.Timer, it's just a wrapper really, so you're using a System.Threading.Timer either way. I mention it because of your comment about using Timers.Timer for server based functionality. It's not really relevant, it's more an ease of use thing afaik.

Comment: Just looked into it some more, here's a nice article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S3 It agrees with your point suggesting that Timers.Timer provides some extra scaffolding to make it thread safe where as Threading.Threading leaves you to do this yourself. So the answer seems to be use Timers.Timer unless you want to roll your own synchronisation code :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be more efficient to simply give the timer a 5 minute period, rather than a 1 minute period and checking the mail every 5th time.

```
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerTick, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Comment: Both are efficient enough. Resource consumption will be indistinguishable from 0.

Comment: EKevin i understand i ll update it and remove the if condition in timer tick.But is timer the only best available option in this scenario

Comment: @HenkHolterman is it possible to implement real-time checking?to monitor changes

Comment: Without more information, we can't answer the question of whether polling is the only option.  Is the app running on a mail server?  If so, is it Exchange or something else?  If it's not running on the server, is a mail client such as Outlook installed?  If Outlook is running, you can subscribe to the NewMail event instead of polling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationevents_11_event.newmail.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The timer is very efficient, but maybe you should use TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) instead and remove the inefficient conditionals in the TimerTick.  Since the TimerTick will run in a ThreadPool thread, you will have to check that the previous event is finished before checking the mail server again.

```
private System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerTick, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

private bool FCheckingMails = false;
void TimerTick(object state)
{
    if (FCheckingMails) return;
    FCheckingMails = true;
    try
    {
        //check mail here
    }
    finally
    {
        FCheckingMails = false;
    }
}
```

Some may say that FCheckingMails is not threadsafe, but it really doesn't need to be.

If you are concerned about efficientcy you should check the code that runs millions of times/minute rather than the code that runs 12 times/hour.

Best luck with your quest.

Answer (score 0):

System.Threading.Timer should be very lightweight in terms of CPU and memory usage, so I wouldn't envisage any problems there. More generally this sort of job is normally triggered by a scheduler that can be configured with more controlm with knowledge of things like weekend days, day of the month (e.g. do processing on first or last day of each month), etc.

If you do go down that route then check out [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/), an open source .net cron job scheduler.